# Is Log4j 2 (version 2.4) support log4j2.properties Properties syntax?

Tags: log4j2

Based on a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485074/log4j-2-doesnt-support-log4j-properties-file-anymore). Is new version(2.4) of log4j [support](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Configuration_with_Properties) log4j2.properties configuration file? Can anyone give me an example of such implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does support .properties as of 2.4: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html#Properties

I would reference their example as it's fairly comprehensive.

Comment: I found a way to use properties configuration, my [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33187689/log4j2-in-a-spring-web-app-with-servlet-3-0/33223753#33223753). The framework has a very poor documentation on this point.